# automatic imagescaling with image or graphicmagick

Tags: imagemagick, typo3

I've got a question that depends on imagemagick:
Is it possible to upload just one picture with a size of 1200px height for example and -depending on device or browser resolution-  reduce the imageheight **AND** size of the image?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditions depending on devices or browser versions. Assuming you like to switch between the folling image heights:

- 600px for IE6,
- 320px for mobile devices,
- 800px for all other devices
  (i.e. regular computers)

Then enter this section to your **template constants**:

```
# for IE6:
[browser = msie] AND [version = 6]
styles.content.imgtext {
        maxH = 600
        maxHInText = 600
}
# for mobile devices:
[useragent = *iPhone*]||[useragent = *iPod*]||[useragent = *Android*]||[useragent = *OperaMini*]||[useragent = *BlackBerry*]
styles.content.imgtext {
        maxH = 320
        maxHInText = 320
}
# For all other browsers
[else]
styles.content.imgtext {
        maxH = 800
        maxHInText = 800
}
[GLOBAL]
```

Alternative solution for **template setup** (explained below):

```
# for IE6:
[browser = msie] AND [version = 6]
tt_content.image.20.1.file {
        maxH = 600
        maxHInText = 600
}
# for mobile devices:
[useragent = *iPhone*]||[useragent = *iPod*]||[useragent = *Android*]||[useragent = *OperaMini*]||[useragent = *BlackBerry*]
tt_content.image.20.1.file {
        maxH = 320
        maxHInText = 320
}
# For all other browsers
[else]
tt_content.image.20.1.file {
        maxH = 800
        maxHInText = 800
}
[GLOBAL]
```

1. These are just some examples of conditions. Check out the [TYPO3 conditions
   reference](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.1.0/view/4/1/) for more ideas.
2. If the recognition of mobile devices does not work correctly with `useragent`, try the extension [cwmobileredirect](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cwmobileredirect/current/). It provides a very reliable mobile device switch.
3. This is about how to set the image *height*. I heard rumours that setting the width (`maxW`) works fine, but setting the height (`maxH`) is buggy somehow in versions below 4.2. Use the alternative solution if problems with maxH occur.

Comment: okay this helps me alot, but its important to know if the images will load their really size or their adjusted smaller size? you know what i mean?

Comment: Imagemagick actually generates the image sizes for you, so in this case three different files will be created. They are not scaled.

Comment: Perfect thats the solution! :)